# value to great for base error from bash associative array

Tags: bash, associative-array

I have  a file called a.txt which looks as follow

```
7A1123123asd 14
8aasdasdasd 15
```

Now I wrote some bash code to read the file and build an associative array from the values in it

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a counter
while read DEAL count; do
    counter["$DEAL"]=$count
done < oasload.job

for i in "${!array[@]}"
do
    echo "key : $i"
    echo "value : ${array[$i]}"
done
```

Unfortunately when I run I get the following error

```
test.sh: line 6: 7A1123123asd: value too great for base (error token is "7A1123123asd")
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like bash treats keys starting with digits as numeric. So, trying to convert 7A it balks because A is not a valid base-10 digit. If you can e.g. prefix all your keys with X throughout, this should fix it.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a counter
while read DEAL count; do
    counter["X$DEAL"]=$count
done < oasload.job

for i in "${!array[@]}"
do
    echo "key : $i"
    echo "value : ${array[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: `declare -a foo; foo["Xa1"]=1; foo["Xz9"]=2; echo "first: ${foo["Xa1"]}, second: ${foo["Xz9"]}, indices: ${!foo[@]}"` gives "first: 2, second: 2, indices: 0"

Comment: Hi what does the `X` mean?

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks OK except that in Bash 4, associative arrays are declared with `-A`. Versions prior to 4 do not support associative arrays. Indexed arrays in any version are declared using `-a` or they are created automatically on assignment using syntax such as `array[7]="element"` or `array=(abc def ghi 123 456)`.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A counter
while read DEAL count; do
    counter["$DEAL"]=$count
done < oasload.job

for i in "${!array[@]}"
do
    echo "key : $i"
    echo "value : ${array[$i]}"
done
```